# How Can I Send the NextAuth Session Token to Express.js Server for Authentication

Tags: express, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I am working on a full stack application where I am building the front end with Next.js and the back end with Express.js.

In the front end, I am using NextAuth for authentication. I am using both credentials and google providers.

I found that I can’t send the session to the express server to authenticate a user for certain endpoints.

How can I protect the express endpoints for users signing with credentials and Google?

I tried to issue http only cookie from the server but it won’t set to cookie when a user use Google sign in. I also tried accessing the NextAuth session token on the server which worked on development only.